# What is the correspondence between each story in Rivka Galchen's "American Innovations" and previously written stories?

Tags: identification-request, short-stories

In the LA Times article, ["Rivka Galchen talks about putting a female twist on iconic stories" by Carolyn Kellogg](http://www.latimes.com/books/jacketcopy/la-ca-jc-rivka-galchen-20140504-story.html), it is claimed that

> "The stories all have female narrators, and all (save one) are inspired by iconic short stories written by men. Galchen's stories are witty and delightfully intelligent, riffing on works by David Foster Wallace, James Joyce and Haruki Murakami. Each illustrates how the presence of women, as authors and narrators, might have inflected canonical stories."

The article mentions three specific correspondences.

1. The titular story "American Innovations" : Gogol's "The Nose"
2. "The Lost Order" : Thurber's "Walter Mitty"
3. "The Region of Unlikeness" : Borges' "The Aleph"

I would like to know the correspondence for each story. I am especially curious to know which story does not map to a previously written work, and also what is the story that corresponds to Galchen's "Real Estate".

For reference, here is the list of stories in her book:

1. The Lost Order
2. The Region of Unlikeness
3. Sticker Shock
4. American Innovations
5. Wild Berry Blue
6. The Entire Northern Side Was Covered with Fire
7. Real Estate
8. Dean of the Arts
9. The Late Novels of Gene Hackman
10. Once an Empire